# curl options in symfony http-client

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, php-curl

I'm refactoring some clients in a `Symfony 4.3` project, to use *Symfony http-client* instead of *Guzzle http-client*. I'm stuck on a client that uses this option in its constructor:

```
'curl.options' => [CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2]
```

I've been reading the docs of Symfony http/client but I can't find any mention of `curl` options. Does someone know something about how to set this option?
I'm configuring headers and other important options in `framework.yaml` for each client.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_client.html#advanced-options points to https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.0/src/Symfony/Contracts/HttpClient/HttpClientInterface.php, and that says you can specify the same parameters as described under https://www.php.net/context.ssl - I guess the `ciphers` would be the relevant one here. https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-ciphers.html lists possible values.

Comment: I had gotten to the php.net/context.ssl but completely missed the ciphers part. Thanks!